# Normal mapping cones and cylinders

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Quick question: we know that if $f :X\to Y$ is a continuous function between Hausdorff spaces, then the mapping cne $C_f$ and the mapping cylinder $M_f$ are also Hausdorff. ¿Can we replace *Hausdorff* by *normal* and keep the statement true?

Answer (score 3):

The mapping cyliner of the identity $\operatorname{id}_X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times [0,1]$. However, some spaces are [Dowker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowker_space), that is: $X$ is normal but $X\times [0,1]$ isn't.

Hence, the answer for mapping cylinders is no.

The mapping cylinder of $\operatorname{id}_X$ embeds into the mapping cone as the closed subspace $X\times[0,\frac 1 2]$ and hence the mapping cone isn't normal for Dowker $X$ as well.

Comment: For the mapping cone note that $CX$ contains a copy of $X\times[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cong X\times I$ as a closed subspace.

Comment: It's worth noting that if $Y$ is normal, then $M_f$ is normal if and only if $X\times I$ is normal.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks, I added the statement for cones to my answer.